# Partial differential equations with related functions

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have $f(x, y) \geq 0$ and $g(x, y) \leq 0$ continuous, such that $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2g}{dy^2}$. Can you show that $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$ or provide a counterexample?

EDIT: $f, g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant prove that $\frac{df}{dx}(0,0)=0$. I assume by $df/dx$ you mean $\partial f/\partial x$. There are many easy counterexamples. Consider $f(x,y)=\sin x + 1$ and $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-2$. Obviously, the 2nd derivatives will match and $\frac{df}{dx}=\cos(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: I don't think this works. Note that the derivative of g is with respect to y, so they don't actually match. There is no typo, I wish to show that df/dx(x,y)= 0.

Comment: I'm slightly confused; $dg/dy=0$, but isn't $df/dx$ still non zero?

Comment: Your example doesn't work since d^2f/dx^2 = -sin(x), while d^2g/dy^2 = 0. The goal is to show that two functions satisfying the criteria must be such that df/dx = dg/dy = 0.

Answer (score 0):

By chosing the domain $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+$ and setting:
$$
f(x,y)=xy \geq 0\\
g(x,y)=-xy \leq 0
$$
Then we have 
$$
f_{xx}=0=g_{yy}
$$
But 
$$
f_x=y \neq 0
$$
If you want an answer for $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the "whole space", just specifiy it in your question. But this answer just came to my mind while reading your question.

Comment: Thanks, edited.